# How to access an associative array using a key position?

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, bit

Let's say I have this code:

```
    $games = [
    "Boys" => ["Danny", "Ben"],
    "Girls" => ["Ashley", "Sandra"]
];
```

And for example, I want to access Danny's name.
I can access it by using

```
$games["Boys"][0]
```

But what if I want to access it by it's bit index (for future `foreach` loops)? I tried something like:

```
 $games[0][0]
```

But I get an error (unindexed something).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to create a numerical array from `$games`, then index that:

```
echo array_values($games)[0][0];
```

Hope that helps

Comment: `As of PHP 5.4 it is possible to array dereference the result of a function or method call directly. Before it was only possible using a temporary variable.`

Comment: @Class Yeah, I had that worry too, but I see OP is using the new PHP 5.4 array syntax, so it's fine.

Comment: true but for any future visitors its nice to say it available for version x and newer otherwise they might get confused